# A super simple Multer question, nested file uploading

Tags: node.js, express, axios, multer

I'm trying to do an image upload with Multer and Express. Doing just an image upload is going fine and everything works, the problem is, I want to send more than just one photo. Let me explain. I got the most basic form ever, not worth sharing. Then when submitting the form with ***JUST*** an image, the axios request looks like this:

```
async onSubmit() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.person.personData.file)
    this.obj.file = formData

    try {
        await axios.post('/projects/new', this.obj.file);
        this.message = 'Uploaded';
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.message = 'Something went wrong'
    }
},
```

The post route in Express to receive the image looks like this:

```
personRoutes.post('/new', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('BODY: ', req.body)
    console.log('REQ.FILE: ', req.file)

    const person = new Person({
        personData: {
            file: req.file.path
        }
    });
    person.save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log('YES', result)
            res.redirect('/projects')
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('KUT', err)
        })
});
```

req.file is the `upload.single('file')` file. Req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any. Ez Pz, so far so good. Now, where things get a bit sketchy is, what if I wanted to upload more than just one photo? So my `obj` object would not only hold a `file` property but a few others aswell. Currently I am directly sending the formData file with

```
await axios.post('/projects/new', this.obj.file);
```

But if my `obj` contained more than just a file, I would have to to this:

```
await axios.post('/projects/new', this.obj);
```

But what in the world should my Express post route look like? Because `req.file` will now (as far as I know) forever be `undefined` because `file` is not defined inside `req` object. It is defined in `req.body` object. Accessing the file as `req.obj.file` won't do anything. Any help would be very much appreciated. I don't even know if it is possible. And if not, what other options do I have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try upload.any() ?

Comment: I've just tried using ```upload.any()```, didn't work. I don't see how using it would change the outcome of my problem :( . Thanks for taking the time to leave a reply.

Answer (score 0):

`upload.array('file')` should work. any number of files will be received.

here is an example:
multer code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "image"+Date.now()+file.originalname);
    }
});
const fileFilter = (req,file,cb)=>{
  if(file.mimetype==="image/jpeg" || file.mimetype==="image/png"){
      cb(null, true);
  }else{
    cb(new Error("File type is not acceptable"),false);
  }
}

const uploadImages = multer({storage:storage,
  limits:{
      fileSize: 1024*1024*10
    },
    fileFilter:fileFilter}).array("shopImage");
```

app.post code:

```
app.post("/shop", function(req,res){
  uploadImages(req,res,function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400).json({message:err.message});
    }else{
      console.log(req.files);
      console.log(req.body);
....
    }
  });
....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Add number of photos need to be upload.
upload.array('photos', 12)
12 represent how many number of pictures you need to upload.